# Select where another column must match one of two specific options

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to get the value from a column on a single table where another column can match one of two cases.

My table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE user_event (
  id SERIAL Primary Key,
  session_id uuid NOT NULL,
  event_name text NOT NULL,
  event_value text NOT NULL
);

-- Test Values
INSERT INTO user_event(session_id, event_name, event_value)
VALUES ('0971ad0b-0b98-4f09-bc93-9ae15c45941b', 'Heading.Click', 'test'),
('0971ad0b-0b98-4f09-bc93-9ae15c45941b', 'Subheading.Click', 'test'),
('0971ad0b-0b98-4f09-bc93-9ae15c45941b', 'Paragraph.Click', 'test'),
('6a627852-5f2a-4884-9949-cf11edf73628', 'Heading.Click', 'test'),
('1e5ec268-34ea-464a-82d1-2cf1e1425df3', 'Heading.Click', 'test'),
('1e5ec268-34ea-464a-82d1-2cf1e1425df3', 'Subheading.Click', 'test'), 
('1e5ec268-34ea-464a-82d1-2cf1e1425df3', 'Page.Impression', 'test');

-- Result
('0971ad0b-0b98-4f09-bc93-9ae15c45941b', '6a627852-5f2a-4884-9949-cf11edf73628')
```

I want to (pseudo sql):

```
SELECT session_id
FROM user_event
WHERE event_name IS Heading.Click
AND other event_name's for the same session_id don't Contain Subheading.Click
OR 
event_name IS Heading.Click
AND other event_name's for the same session_id must contain both (Subheading.Click,
Paragraph.Click)
```

So far I've come up with an incredibly inefficient way of doing this

```
SELECT session_id
FROM user_event
WHERE event_name = 'Heading.Click'
AND 
(session_id not in (select session_id from user_event where event_name != 'Heading.Click')
OR
(session_id in (select session_id from user_event where event_name = 'Subheading.Click')
AND session_id in (select session_id from user_event where event_name = 'Paragraph.Click')
));
```

Here is a fiddle setup that I've been using to test this. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/a55a3/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could rewrite your query as

```
SELECT session_id
FROM user_event
GROUP BY session_id
HAVING 
    SUM(CASE WHEN event_name = 'Heading.Click' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >0
    AND (
        SUM(CASE WHEN event_name = 'Subheading.Click' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) =0
        OR (
            SUM(CASE WHEN event_name = 'Subheading.Click' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
            AND 
            SUM(CASE WHEN event_name = 'Paragraph.Click' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
        ) 
    )
```

There is no need of sub-queries, you could use conditional aggregation to match your criteria for each session id.

[Demo](https://rextester.com/DXFCA81635)

Comment: I don't think that is working. Its returning the `1e5ec268-34ea-464a-82d1-2cf1e1425df3` session that doesn't contain `Paragraph.Click`

Comment: @Stephen My bad, I have updated query see updated answer

Comment: Thank you! Its much faster than my attempt.

Comment: @GordonLinoff are you sure? The demo returns the correct results.

Comment: @Stephen . . . Never mind, the two pseudo-code examples are inconsistent.